# Multi screen/Monitor Management

Tags: c#, .net, multiscreen

Does the index in array Screen.AllScreens map to the Screen number as shown by the operating system?

Comment: Logically it should. I'm sure it does for the `PrimaryScreen` but I can't really test it with just 2 monitors.

Comment: Why do you have doubts about?

Comment: Suppose there are 6 screens and 4 of them are wall screens. Wall screen numbers can be configured in a setting file. Now, How do I programmatically identify screen numbers? How do I identify wall screens?

Answer (score 2):

In [this thread on MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues/thread/668e3cf9-4e00-4b40-a6f8-c7d2fc1afd39), Jialiang Ge of Microsoft states:

> I discussed this with the Shell team. Here is the team's response:
>
> There is not a supported way to figour [sic] out the IDs that you referred to programmatically. It was never a design goal to provide a way for applications to label monitors with the same IDs that the screen resolution control panel uses. What is your application trying to accomplish?